# Command to retrieve all non-empty block-content from Excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, powershell, xlsx

I have a sheet `DataRepo` about the size of 300 rows and 10 rows, about 300 such Excel files in XLSX format. I need to read each Excel file and store it as a CSV (because original XLSX files are corrupted with KeyError, other methods in Python/R resulting to KeyError unless resaving manually with Excel).

I am currently using `$Sheet.Cells.Item(row, col).Text` to get single value as text but the need over the whole block: either I need to 2-loop over the block and save it CSV or find some ready method for the `$Sheet`, any ready PowerShell method available? Which looping options available in PowerShell?

How can I retrieve all non-empty content in an Excel sheet with PowerShell?

```bsh
$XLSDoc = 'C:\Users\hhh\Desktop\1.xlsx'
$SheetName = "DataRepo"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($XLSDoc)
$Sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($SheetName)

#Get data:
$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,2).Text
```

Can I do something similar to VBA in PowerShell?

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 1
j = 1

Do While i < 10
    Do While j < 10
        Sheet.Cells.Item(i, j).Text
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Can't you simply save each sheet as a separate CSV?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers yes it is possible like appending each sheet name to each file name, how would you do that programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this to export each worksheet to a separate CSV:

```
$wbName = $Workbook.Name
$wbPath = $Workbook.Path
$Workbook.Worksheets | ForEach-Object {
  $csvName = Join-Path $wbPath ('{0}_{1}.csv' -f $wbName, $_.Name)
  $_.SaveAs($csvName, 6)
}
```

Comment: The method items() in `$Workbook.Worksheets.Items()` is missing, why? Did you mean to use some other object with the method? `Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Items'`

Comment: @hhh Sorry, I typed that from (apparently failing) memory yesterday. It's actually just `$Workbook.Worksheets`. Fixed.

Comment: Can you use the same `SaveAs` command to save the file as tab-separated-file TSV or with other deliminator? Is it MSDN where you can see the docs about the commands of Powershell? What is the `6` in the SaveAs command?

Comment: 6 is the numeric value of the `xlCSV` fileformat constant. You can get a list of all values by following the link to the `XlFileFormat` enumeration in the [`Workbook.SaveAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff841185.aspx) documentation. For tab-delimited text I think you need -4158 (`xlText` or `xlCurrentPlatformText`).

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates a function out of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42912877/164148) and then loop over all of the xlsx files in the directory, replacement and trimming added to avoid 216 chars limit per file. Then it outputs the CSV files to the directory of each sheet.

```
 Function ExportXLSXToCSVs ($XLSDoc)
 {
     $Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
     $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($XLSDoc)

     $wbName = $Workbook.Name
     $wbPath = $Workbook.Path
     $Workbook.Worksheets | ForEach-Object {
         $csvName = Join-Path $wbPath ('{0}_{1}.csv' -f $wbName, $_.Name)

         #Trim/replacements added to avoid the limit 216 chars per file
         $csvName = $csvName.Trim().Replace(" ", "")
         $_.SaveAs($csvName, 6)        #CSV
     }
 }

 #DEMO 1 over a single file
 #ExportXLSXToCSVs('C:\Users\hhh\Desktop\1.xlsx')

 #DEMO 2 over all files in a directory
 Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\hhh\Desktop\Data\" -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
     $myFile = $_.DirectoryName +"\"+ $_.Name
     ExportXLSXToCSVs($myFile)
 }
```